# Client side download of image created by the user

Tags: php, imagejpeg

I know very little about php so sorry for any stupid mistakes. I found this code online but is not exactly what I want.

As seen below, I am displaying a form where the user writes something then clicks the "CRIAR SELO" button, the page get's refreshed and that text is put on to an image and displayed for him to download using the right mouse button.

[image: Image 1]

I want that when the user clicks the "CRIAR SELO" button, a window is displayed so he can choose where to save the file in his computer, so that there's no need to right click and save.

*I don't need to keep displaying the image, so if it's not possible to do both (display and force download window) there's no problem.

Here's the form (index.php):

```
<?php $rda = isset($_GET['rda'])?$_GET['rda']:"00000BR"; ?>
<form action="" method="get" />
    <input name="rda" type="text" value="" placeholder="00000BR">
    <img src="selo.php?rda=<?php echo $rda ?>">
    <input type="submit" name="enviar" class="confirma" value="CRIAR SELO »">
</form>
```

And here's the PHP (selo.php):

```
<?php
$imagem = imagecreatefromjpeg( "00000BR_01.jpg" );
$cor = imagecolorallocate( $imagem, 000, 000, 000 );
$font = "verdanab.ttf";
$rda = urldecode( $_GET['rda'] );
imagettftext($imagem, 20, 0, 37, 50, $cor, $font, $rda );
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg( $imagem, '', 100 );
imagedestroy($imagem);
?>
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Try to add - header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="picture.jpg"'); after 1st header

Comment: @AlexeyShatrov Hi, thank you for the reply. I tried what you suggested but unfortunately didn't work.

Comment: You're apparently not asking for client-side download (something really tricky, since there's no way to emulate HTTP headers from client-side JavaScript) but good old server-side stuff. `Content-Disposition: attachment` in indeed the solution. How exactly does it not work for you? Is the header not generated? Is it being ignored by browser? Is download corrupt? Something else?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I don't know if it's not being generated or ignored (sorry, don't know much about the subject), nothing changed after adding Alexey's sugestion. I edited the question to express my self a little better . I want that when the user clicks the "CRIAR SELO" button, a window is displayed so he can choose where to save the file in his computer.

Comment: @AlanFranco Unless I'm missing something, none of your updates attempt to answer that. If the problem is that image is saved in the default *Downloads* folder, well, that's a browser feature you can't control.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Figured out, I'm sorry, I probably didn't express myself right. Thank you for the attention.

Comment: Please read [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Don't add the word "Solved" to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way.

I added a second button, so now the user clicks on "CRIAR SELO" to generate the image with his text and then clicks the button "DOWNLOAD" to download the generated image with the name of the text.

Ex: User types "77777BR", clicks "CRIAR SELO" and then "DOWNLOAD" to download a image called "7777BR.jpg".

```
<?php $rda = isset($_GET['rda'])?$_GET['rda']:"00000BR"; ?>
<form action="" method="get">
    <input name="rda" type="text" placeholder="00000BR">
    <br />
    <img src="selo.php?rda=<?php echo $rda ?>">
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="enviar" class="confirma" value="CRIAR SELO »">
    <a href="selo.php?rda=<?php echo $rda ?>" download="<?php echo $rda.'.jpg' ?>">DOWNLOAD</a>
</form>
```